# Do excited states of hydrogen give cosmologically relevant hyperfine transitions?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, perturbation-theory, hydrogen, hyperfine-structure

In Griffiths quantum mechanics, there's a discussion of hyperfine splitting for the ground state of hydrogen - this gives rise to a small level splitting corresponding to an emitted wavelength of $21$ cm. Though I don't have much background in cosmology, I believe that an emission spectrum showing such lines is used to map out the presence of hydrogen gas clouds in in our galaxy.

Are there corresponding lines from hyperfine transitions in the excited states of hydrogen that are observed?

---

For example, I would expect that the $n=2, j=1/2, l=0$ states would have a hyperfine splitting of $1/8$ the magnitude of that in the ground state, following from the fact that the $n=2, l=0$ state has a wavefunction with amplitude $\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$ smaller at $r=0$ than $n=1, l=0$. This would correspond to a $168$ cm line for a hyperfine transition between the two $n=2, j=1/2, l=0$ hyperfine energy levels.

Is such a $168$ cm line observed? My instinct is that it might be difficult to see this transition - I suspect there will be a transition from $n=2$ to $n=1$ much faster than a transition in the hyperfine levels.

---

I should probably emphasize the part of the question that I'm most interested in - is there a theoretical reason from atomic physics why a $168$ cm line would be difficult to observe? As noted in the comments, there's a practical obstacle being that the corresponding radio frequencies for such a transition are dedicated for television broadcasting.

Comment: there's no radioastronomy allocation there: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/United_States_Frequency_Allocations_Chart_2016_-_The_Radio_Spectrum.pdf

Comment: @JEB, thanks, neat image. I see that the desired $178$ MHz is to the left end of the block for television broadcasting. I hadn't appreciated that this sort of thing put limits on radio astronomy, but in hindsight it makes sense. Besides this practical limitation, do you think there's also a theoretical limitation coming from the fact that hyperfine transitions are relatively slow?

Comment: If I knew that I would have answered. All I know is 21cm is locked out for radio Astronomy/

Comment: @JEB Radio astronomy isn't restricted to allocated bands, although you may need to go to a remote location to minimize interference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the hyperfine lines for higher-order $n$ states are less useful than for $1s$ because they are allowed to decay via ordinary dipole-allowed (or higher-order) transitions which emit optical/UV light, not RF.

For states except $2s$, these decay pathways give the states an intrinsic linewidth broadening, so you cannot readily observe their hyperfine splittings spectroscopically for higher $n$, outside of laboratory conditions. For reference, the hydrogen $2p$-state lifetime is 1.6ns (48cm) which would wash out the smaller hyperfine splitting in the frequency domain. The spontaneous decay to $1s$ is also much more probable than radio emission between the hyperfine states, so RF emission from those excited states is very weak even when they are populated.

The $2s$ state is special because it cannot decay via single photon transitions. So the lifetime is much longer and the hyperfine splitting could be observed spectroscopically. However, its decay rate is on the order of 100 milliseconds, which is still much faster than the hyperfine lifetime by orders of magnitude.

An additional reason is that the temperatures needed to populate the excited states are enormous, so the Doppler broadening would also wash out the hyperfine splitting for higher $n$ states even if the intrinsic linewidth did not. I suppose you could use the excited state hyperfine RF radiation to do thermometry, but the required temperature to populate those levels is so high that I would suspect you would have hydrogen in the plasma phase rather than as hot atoms.

In particular, you can reference the phase diagram below for hydrogen (vertical axis in Kelvin). The energy difference between $1s$ and $2p$ is about 10 eV (about $10^5$ Kelvin) for reference.

[image]

Comment: Another factor is that the radio background from energetic electrons in space (synchrotron radiation) rises rapidly as the wavelength increases. That makes long wavelength lines harder to detect.

Comment: Very nice answer. I hadn't appreciated that the temperatures needed to appreciably populate the $n=2$ levels already corresponded to a plasma phase. This makes sense in hindsight; to populate $n=2$ ($k_B T$ of order $3/4$ a Rydberg above the ground state) would allow for significant probability of occupying unbound states (energy larger than a Rydberg above the ground state), and there's probably a high entropy for such unbound states increasing the probability of being unbound relative to the probability of occupying the $n=2$ levels.

Comment: @user196574 precisely, you could perhaps crunch some numbers for temperatures of interest and even figure out how quickly the hydrogen atom would ionize. I suspect it would be extremely quickly (sub-femtosecond?)